# Imagehandler does not show image from remote request

Tags: c#, asp.net, handler

Hi I wrote this image handler code and It works fine on my local and shows the image in the page , NOW I have uploaded it on a host and when I request the page from remote the image does not show up in the image control ! any help ?!

```
    <%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Handler" %>

using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web;

public class Handler : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
{

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IranQRDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            string TableName = context.Session["TableToQuery"].ToString();
            string ID = context.Session["ID"].ToString();

            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + TableName + " WHERE ID=" + ID, conn);

            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Read();
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr["Image"]);
            conn.Close();

        }
        catch
        {
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM DefaultImage WHERE ID=1", conn);

            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Read();
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr["Image"]);
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

my connectionstring :

```
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=myDatasource;Initial Catalog=DB;User Id=myusername;Password=mypassword"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and here is the datalist in wich I show the image :

' />
                                        
                                    
                                    
                                        
                                            '>

I checked my database , the data is inserted properly and text data is postback to my page but only the image does not show up

and here is my part of webconfig :

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
        <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
        <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
        <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
        <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
        <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Have you added handler path to hadler section, connection string to new DB? IIS version is the same? Try to clean previous registered handlers before declare own.

Comment: @user854301 No I have not added anything to connectionstring and I dont know how to do that :( would you help me plz

Comment: First check whtether "IranQRDBConnectionString" connection string persists in your web.config\connectionStrings. Than you can verify yours web.config\system.webServer\handlers section.

Comment: @user854301 I added the part system.web  of my webconfig , and I can insert data corectly to my db and data returns to me but only the image does not show up

Comment: I can't see yours handler in 'handlers' section.

Comment: @user854301 How  should I add that ? I found this in codeproject website : <add name="ImageHandler" verb="*" path="*.jpg" type="ImageHandler"/> is this correct and enough to add  ?

Comment: in your case it should be somethnig like <add name="ImageHandler" verb="" path=".jpg" type="YOUR.NAMESPACE.Handler"/>

Comment: @user854301 thx alot , I have precompiled my Handler class and It's in my bin folder can I so is it right to set the type property this way : type="Handler"

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx - how to register handler

Comment: @user854301 This is the name of the dll file in my bin folder : App_Web_handler.ashx.cdcab7d2.dll     so should type be like this : type="Handler, App_Web_handler.ashx.cdcab7d2.dll"

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are not always disposing of your database connections.  If an Exception is thown in your *catch* block, you will not close that connection.  Also, if an Exception is thrown in the *try* block after *conn.Open()*, you will end up opening the connection twice.  *Always* use a *using* statement to manage the lifecycle of resources that implement *IDisposable*.

Second, Catching an Exception as a means to fall back to a default image is not good style.  In fact, you may be leaking resources (it's not clear to me reading the code exactly where the Exception is being thrown).

As for the core issue, I do not believe there is enough information to answer why the images are not showing up after you deploy the code.

Are your database connection strings correct?  What do you get back from your first

```
comm.ExecuteReader()
```

?

If an Exception is thrown, what Exception and where?

If you add logging to your code to answer those questions, there is an excellent chance that the source of the problem will become apparent.  If not, update your question with those answers.

Comment: My connectionstring is cerect and I checked my database data is inserted coreclt and text data is postedback to my page but only the image does not show up :(

Comment: I added more details to my code , I checkd the remote database , data is inserted corecly to my db and data is returned to my page in postback either but only the image does not show up !

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you try by using query string except using the Seesion. Here is my code where in query string is used and i fetch images from the database without having to create the any instatnce of that desired image inyour local folder. Hop this helps.

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="DisplayImg" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class DisplayImg : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string theID;
        if (context.Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
            theID = context.Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("No parameter specified");

        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        Stream strm = DisplayImage(theID);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        int byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 2048);

        while (byteSeq > 0)
        {
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteSeq);
            byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 2048);
        }
    }

    public Stream DisplayImage(string theID)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SERVER"].ConnectionString.ToString());
        string sql = "SELECT Server_image_icon FROM tbl_ServerMaster WHERE server_Code = @ID";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", theID);
        connection.Open();
        object theImg = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        try
        {
            return new MemoryStream((byte[])theImg);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Just add one line in CS code

```
UploadImg.ImageUrl = "~/DisplayImg.ashx?id=" + code;
```